# Can I build and debug c++ programs on remote machine?

Tags: c++, eclipse, build, debugging

I am on windows XP want to build the programs on linux remote pc
i have eclipse Ganymede, CDT, RSE installed on remote machine... but how to configure all this?
am I doing correct? could anybody suggest

Answer (score 0):

You could access your remote machine using VNC or similar remote desktop infrastructures. That would allow you to work with Eclipse (edit, build, run, debug, etc) as you would in your local machine.

If bandwidth is too narrow or you don't manage the Linux box, you could access via SSH or telnet and work in console mode (with Emacs/Vim, gdb and all that stuff).

Comment: thx for reply..but i have not installed eclipse on remote machine ..its on my local windows machine i can connect through RSE ..but i want to build and debug in thr itself? i mean when i say 'build' it should build the prog and show me errors on my console... n next debug if possible??

Comment: may be my question is wrong..i want toask like how can i build and debug programs from my local eclipse to remote pc

Comment: Ok, now that you rephrased your question, what you need is a cross development setup, that allows you to build programs for a different environment (operating system/architecture).

In this particular case, you need a set of C/C++ compilers for Windows which can output Linux binaries. Search the web for versions of Windows compilers able to do this.

Once you have such compiler installed, configure your Eclipse environment to use it and setup some kind of script that transfers the binary to the target machine.

Then remote-debug it using this: http://davis.lbl.gov/Manuals/GDB/gdb_17.html

Comment: thx for understanding,, currently i have configured it so that i can debug run and debug(still not upto the mark) on my local windows machine ...using CDT 5.0.2 + gdb 6.8 + cygwin + windows combination.
but still not successful for remote program build (target : linux solaries) yet.. looking for some more help

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://github.com/ericwoodruff/rmake you would configure your IDE and edit code locally but it uses rsync to build on the remote machine. I've used it at HP to build C++ programs across multiple platforms, linux->windows, windows->linux. It works in the command line and I've used an eclipse builder to invoke it as well. If you enable --no-decorate Eclipse can even parse the build output into the problems view.